# Merging two sequences in scala in an orderly fashion

Tags: scala, sequence

I am trying to merge two sequences such that they remain sorted. The following is the code that I have written:

```
  val seq1 = Seq(1,3,5,7,9)
  val seq2 = Seq(2,4,6,8)
  var arr = Seq[Int]()
  for(b <- seq2)
  {
    for(a <- seq1)
    {
      if(a < b)
        arr = arr :+ a
      else
      {
        arr = arr :+ b;break; 
      }
    }
  }
  println(arr)
```

the output that I require needs to be :

```
Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

But it seems break does not work in Scala. I am relatively new to the language. What would be the best way to carry out this operation?

Comment: I think it's worth emphasizing in your question that the two input sequences **are already sorted**, and if not, this would presumably be an error. Is that correct?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be this:

```
(seq1 ++ seq2).sorted
```

If `seq1` and `seq2` contain some other type, you'll have to provide an `Ordering` for that type; or, alternatively, use the `sortBy` method, mapping each element to an element of another type for which an `Ordering` can implicitly be found:

```
(seq1 ++ seq2).sortBy(_.toDate)
```

Comment: What if I had dates (elements of type LocalDate to be precise) instead of elements of type Int in the above example? method sorted does not work on dates. what do you suggest?

Comment: Is there a way to sortBy two types? Like toDate, toPriority? so that it will be first ordered toDate and then toPriority?

Comment: `sortBy(x => (x.toDate, x.toPriority))`

Answer (score 9):

The following also works for non-interleaved sequences:

```
def mergeSorted[E: Ordering](x: Seq[E], y: Seq[E]): Seq[E] = {
  val ordering = implicitly[Ordering[E]]
  @tailrec
  def rec(x: Seq[E], y: Seq[E], acc: Seq[E]): Seq[E] = {
    (x, y) match {
      case (Nil, Nil) => acc
      case (_, Nil)   => acc ++ x
      case (Nil, _)   => acc ++ y
      case (xh :: xt, yh :: yt) =>
        if (ordering.lteq(xh, yh))
          rec(xt, y, acc :+ xh)
        else
          rec(x, yt, acc :+ yh)
    }
  }
  rec(x, y, Seq())
}
```

Please note that for performance reasons you'd probably use Builders (vs. :+, +:, reverse).

Answer (score 6):

I was happy to find @CaringDev's solution and to adapt it to use a `Builder`:

```
def mergeSortedBuilder[E: Ordering](x: Seq[E], y: Seq[E])(implicit ordering: Ordering[E]): Seq[E] = {
  @tailrec
  def rec(x: Seq[E], y: Seq[E], acc: Builder[E, Seq[E]]): Builder[E, Seq[E]] = {
  (x, y) match {
    case (Nil, Nil) => acc
    case (_, Nil)   => acc ++= x
    case (Nil, _)   => acc ++= y
    case (xh :: xt, yh :: yt) =>
      if (ordering.lteq(xh, yh))
        rec(xt, y, acc += xh)
      else
        rec(x, yt, acc += yh)
  }
}
rec(x, y, Seq.newBuilder).result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To interleave two sequences while maintaining their individual ordering, you can use:

```
scala> seq1.zip(seq2).flatMap(pair => Seq(pair._1,pair._2))
res1: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Note, however, that for sequences of unequal length this loses the extra elements of the longer sequence. That can be sorted out with a bit more effort (find the longer of the two lists, and add `longer.drop(shorter.length)`).

Comment: I am sorry. I had forgotten to add the element '9' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interleave an arbitrary number of sequences in order, you can use something like

```
implicit class Interleave[T](input: Seq[Seq[T]]) {
  def interleave: Seq[T] = {
    input.foldLeft(Seq[Seq[T]]()) { (acc, cur) =>
      if (acc.isEmpty) cur.map { m => Seq(m) }
      else (acc zip cur).map { case (sequence, m) =>
        sequence :+ m
      }
    }.flatten.toVector
  }
}
```

It may be possible to improve the performance on this, particularly as the `toVector` is there primarily to transform the stream into something eager.

Usage looks something like

```
Seq(Seq(1,2), Seq(2,3), Seq(3,4)).interleave should be(Seq(1,2,3,2,3,4))
```